# Using ls command with a 'path' to display contents inside of a directory

Tags: command-line, directory, paths, ls

Okay, so I have three questions that regard to the title.

1. How do I use the ls command with an absolute path to display the contents of a directory? For example, the /home/documents directory?
2. How do I use the ls command with a relative path to display the contents of that 'Documents' directory.
3. How do I use the ls command with another version of the relative path to display the contents of that 'Documents' directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A straightforward demonstration:

1. **Absolute path:**

   ```
   andrew@ilium~$ ls -l ~/Documents/
   total 204
   -rw-r--r-- 1 andrew users 191413 Mar  7  2014 Claim-Form-1112.pdf
   drwxr-xr-x 3 andrew users   4096 Sep 15 11:19 Nested
   -rw-r--r-- 1 andrew users    498 Feb 27  2014 backspace_mutt
   -rw-r--r-- 1 andrew users     59 Mar  7  2010 clock
   -rw-r--r-- 1 andrew users    120 Jun 29  2015 daily
   andrew@ilium~$
   ```
2. **Relative path:**

   ```
    andrew@ilium~$ cd Documents/Nested/
    andrew@ilium~/Documents/Nested$ ls -l ..
    total 204
    -rw-r--r-- 1 andrew users 191413 Mar  7  2014 Claim-Form-1112.pdf
    drwxr-xr-x 3 andrew users   4096 Sep 15 11:19 Nested
    -rw-r--r-- 1 andrew users    498 Feb 27  2014 backspace_mutt
    -rw-r--r-- 1 andrew users     59 Mar  7  2010 clock
    -rw-r--r-- 1 andrew users    120 Jun 29  2015 daily
    andrew@ilium~/Documents/Nested$
   ```
3. **Relative path (2)**

   ```
   andrew@ilium~$ cd Documents/Nested/Nested_Further/
   andrew@ilium~/Documents/Nested/Nested_Further$ ls -l ../../
   total 204
   -rw-r--r-- 1 andrew users 191413 Mar  7  2014 Claim-Form-1112.pdf
   drwxr-xr-x 3 andrew users   4096 Sep 15 11:19 Nested
   -rw-r--r-- 1 andrew users    498 Feb 27  2014 backspace_mutt
   -rw-r--r-- 1 andrew users     59 Mar  7  2010 clock
   -rw-r--r-- 1 andrew users    120 Jun 29  2015 daily
   andrew@ilium~/Documents/Nested/Nested_Further$
   ```
4. **Bonus 'Combo':**

   ```
   andrew@ilium~$ ls -l ~/Documents/Nested/Nested_Further/../../
   total 204
   -rw-r--r-- 1 andrew users 191413 Mar  7  2014 Claim-Form-1112.pdf
   drwxr-xr-x 3 andrew users   4096 Sep 15 11:19 Nested
   -rw-r--r-- 1 andrew users    498 Feb 27  2014 backspace_mutt
   -rw-r--r-- 1 andrew users     59 Mar  7  2010 clock
   -rw-r--r-- 1 andrew users    120 Jun 29  2015 daily
   andrew@ilium~$
   ```

OK so the last one is a bit silly but you get the idea :)

**Further Reading:**

- [Absolute path vs relative path in Linux/Unix](http://www.linuxnix.com/abslute-path-vs-relative-path-in-linuxunix/)

Comment: Glad the answer has been useful! And have a great day :)